# Rowcolor wont cover all cells in the row

Tags: tables, color

The following code

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}| |m{10cm}|}

\hline

\rowcolor[gray]{0.9} \centering Grupo & \centering Descrição \tabularnewline
\hline
\hline


2B & instalações que utilizam fontes seladas em equipamentos para fins de radiografia industrial \tabularnewline
\hline
7B & instalações radiativas que utilizam equipamentos geradores de radiação ionizante que produzem feixe com energia maior que 0,10 MeV e menor ou igual a 0,60 Mev \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

inside my project, produces the following table:

[image]

As you can see, `\rowcolor` isn't working the way I wanted it to do.

However, when I paste the code in a new document, the `\rowcolor` works fine.

Whats happening?

---

UPDATE

It looks like a font family issue. I was using:

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Then I outcomment the `helvet` package

```
  %\usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

and the tables are fixed.

But now my document is ugly. I really miss `helvet` package. What could I do?

---

Update:

posting the whole code now, so you can see the problem too (simplified version, just to reproduce the problem)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}| |m{10cm}|}

\hline

\rowcolor[gray]{0.9} \centering Grupo & \centering Descrição \tabularnewline
\hline
\hline


A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm using ubuntu, texstudio and pdflatex to compile the code.

I've found that the problem is the word "Descrição" - when I change it to anything  without latin, like just "Descr", rowcolor works even with the helvet package.

---

UPDATE 2013-10-31-03:57 PM

super simplified example, which reproduces the rowcolor problem, as requested:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}| |m{10cm}|}

\hline

\rowcolor[gray]{0.9} \centering Grupo & \centering Descrição \tabularnewline
\hline
\hline


A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and now, the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.4.1)  31 OCT 2013 15:56
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**root.tex
(./root.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo
File: bk11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/home/erickfis/texmf/tex/latex/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count88
\float@exts=\toks14
\float@box=\box26
\@float@everytoks=\toks15
\@floatcapt=\box27
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count89
\mult@box=\box28
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen103
\c@unbalance=\count90
\c@collectmore=\count91
\doublecol@number=\count92
\multicoltolerance=\count93
\multicolpretolerance=\count94
\full@width=\dimen104
\page@free=\dimen105
\premulticols=\dimen106
\postmulticols=\dimen107
\multicolsep=\skip43
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip44
\partial@page=\box29
\last@line=\box30
\mult@rightbox=\box31
\mult@grightbox=\box32
\mult@gfirstbox=\box33
\mult@firstbox=\box34
\@tempa=\box35
\@tempa=\box36
\@tempa=\box37
\@tempa=\box38
\@tempa=\box39
\@tempa=\box40
\@tempa=\box41
\@tempa=\box42
\@tempa=\box43
\@tempa=\box44
\@tempa=\box45
\@tempa=\box46
\@tempa=\box47
\@tempa=\box48
\@tempa=\box49
\@tempa=\box50
\@tempa=\box51
\c@columnbadness=\count95
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count96
\last@try=\dimen108
\multicolovershoot=\dimen109
\multicolundershoot=\dimen110
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box52
\colbreak@box=\box53
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen111
\extrarowheight=\dimen112
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip45
\backup@length=\skip46
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2010/03/12 v0.04p Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count97
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2001/02/13 v0.1j Color table columns (DPC)
\everycr=\toks17
\minrowclearance=\skip47
)
\rownum=\count98
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/home/erickfis/texmf/tex/latex/multirow.sty
\bigstrutjot=\dimen113
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/portuges.ldf
Language: portuges 2008/03/18 v1.2q Portuguese support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2008/07/06 v3.8l Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count99
\U@D=\dimen114
)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Portuguese'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.

\l@portuges = a dialect from \language0
\l@brazilian = a dialect from \language\l@portuges 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 145.
)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks18
\inpenc@posthook=\toks19

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen115
\TX@old@table=\dimen116
\TX@old@col=\dimen117
\TX@target=\dimen118
\TX@delta=\dimen119
\TX@cols=\count100
\TX@ftn=\toks20
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)) (./root.aux)
\openout1 = `root.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+phv on input line 18.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count101
\scratchdimen=\dimen120
\scratchbox=\box54
\nofMPsegments=\count102
\nofMParguments=\count103
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count104
\MPscratchDim=\dimen121
\MPnumerator=\count105
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 23.

Overfull \hbox (2.14104pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 27--27
 []|\OT1/phv/m/n/10.95 Grupo| 
 []

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./root.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2123 strings out of 495061
 25048 string characters out of 1182622
 85158 words of memory out of 3000000
 5303 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 8808 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,14n,35p,187b,191s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/sha
re/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb>
Output written on root.pdf (1 page, 7827 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Obviously something in your document disturbs the commands. So it would be a good idea, if you would show a small but *complete*  example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I commented out the code until I could find and isolate the problem

Comment: the problems is the font family \usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} - removing %\usepackage{helvet} fix the rowcolor, but now my document is ugly...

Comment: Show a *complete* example. Code snippets are useless.

Comment: You do really need a complete example that shows the problem. I embedded your tabular in a document with enough packages to make it compile and the entire first row had a gray background. This is with or without the `helvet` package and with or without the change to `\familydefault`.

Comment: I've just posted a complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: No problem here, but remove the line `\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}` it is senseless, you are already loading both packages earlier.  Then remove 10 more packages from the list (try out which can be removed), compile and show the log-file.

Comment: done - removed a lot of packages and included the log file

Comment: @erickfis I get the “Descrição” cell with a grey background.

Comment: maybe its a ubuntu issue, go figure....

Comment: Your system is quite old and more importantly your colortbl is *very* old: colortbl 2001/02/13 v0.1j. I have colortbl 2012/02/13 v1.0a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ulrike-fischer pointed out, my tex installation had very old packages.
I was using the ubuntu 12.04 packages, wich I got from the ubuntu repositories.

Then I upgrade my tex install following the instructions found in
[How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

and now the rowcolor is working properly with helvet package and latin characters.

thank you ulrike!

Comment: someone should stick in the front page the instructions to upgrade tex distribution. Something like: "before asking, make sure you have the latest software. To update your tex, see these instructions"...